# Outputting controller variable in Ember.js HTMLbars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars

I was following with along the [Ember Guides: Defining Your Routes](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/defining-your-routes/) and added a customized index route in my Ember app; which sets a controller title property:

```
// app/routes/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    // Set the IndexController's `title`
    controller.set('title', 'Tagged! - home');
  }
});
```

I then added an output for the title in `app/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    {{content-for 'head'}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tagged-ember.css">

    {{content-for 'head-footer'}}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{content-for 'body'}}

    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/tagged-ember.js"></script>

    {{content-for 'body-footer'}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**However instead of the expected output I get `{{title}}` in the browser title bar. Why is HTMLbars not outputting the variable?**

I'm using the `ember-cli` (ember 1.13.3) and running the server with `ember server`. I can see the controller property in the ember inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index.html` file is outside the scope of the application controller/route/template, [ember-cli-document-title](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-document-title) solves the issue for you.

If you don't want to use it you can create an [in-repo-addon](http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#detailed-list-of-blueprints-and-their-use) that makes use of something like `{{content-for 'document-title'}}`.

Comment: That kind of makes sense, is this just a case of Embers crazy speed of development outrunning the docs?

Comment: The docs are up to par (in a way), this is not anything new and is a common functionality people look for, the thing is the application controller can't output anything outside of the application template `application.hbs` and the application template is included in the index via the `{{content-for 'body'}}` tag.

Comment: Thats just silly - docs should have examples which actually work. Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to do and what is mentioned in the guide are 2 very different things, the guides are correct, they are setting a title inside the page, you are going for the `<title>` tag, there is no mention of that in the guide.

Comment: Oops, I really missread that - in the guide they are printing it out in a `<h1>` tag